# only selected view modes per node?

Tags: display-suite

The view mode per node option in DS Extras is great. But I want to give my editors only the 2 view modes they need, I don't want to burden them with the complete list of some 20 view modes I use all over the site. Is it possible to configure this?

Thanks for any help
Kind greetings
Frank

Answer (score 0):

This functionality appears to already be in the current release of Display Suite.  See here for details: https://www.drupal.org/node/1673626

Comment: Thanks for your reply Aaron. I know I can make view modes available for a contenttype, eg article. But I have some 20 view modes that I use for the article contenttype and there are only maybe 3 of them that should be really available for my editors (for them choosing how to format ana article detail). The other 17 are for admin configuration work (eg article teaser on some pages etc).

Comment: Yes, I  understand that.  If you look at that link it is actually referring to the functionality you want.  Have you tried the latest release of DS?

Comment: Visit the "edit" form for your content type at admin/structure/types/manage/{contenttype} and you'll be able to choose the view modes you want available for that interface: http://screencast.com/t/jZ7IPAJ2Ws2